# Google Cloud Storage Signed URL with Google App Engine using Django with Search Filters

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, django-rest-framework, google-cloud-storage, google-app-engine-python

I have the following model with relevant fields and an api with all the model fields returning correctly.

```
class VideoEntityFilterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Entity
        fields = ('uuid', 'description', 'url', 'segment_start', 'segment_end', 'confidence', 'username', 'userid', 'videouuid', 'videotitle')

class VideoEntityList(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = Entity
    serializer_class = VideoEntityFilterSerializer
    queryset = Entity.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['videouuid', ]
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
```

I need to add a dynamic field the "signed url" for providing access for a particular authorised user along with actual google storage url at the time of the request.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct is answer is below using SerializerMethodField :

```
class VideoEntityFilterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  signed_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_signed_url')

  def get_signed_url(self, foo):
      return foo.name == "bar" 

  class Meta:
    model = Entity
    fields = ('uuid', 'description', 'url', 'segment_start', 'segment_end', 'confidence', 'username', 'userid', 'videouuid', 'videotitle', 'signed_url')
```